# passing pointcloud xyzi to octomap

Tags: octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using `octomap` to process some radar data that is stored in a `PointCloud2` object. It is working correctly, but I am unclear as to what values the points in the cloud should contain.

For my case, I am storing my data in a cloud of `PointXYZI`. At the moment I am just trying thresholding the data and setting the intensity of each point either low or high. This doesn't seem to be really altering anything and the octomap generated thinks every point in every cloud is occupied.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I have read the Octomap paper but can't seem to get it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203062/passing-pointcloud-xyzi-to-octomap/) by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Per default, octomap only cares about the geometric information, not the additional field like intensity or rgb data that is contained in some point clouds. There is functionality in Octomap for also using color information (see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/45836/colored-octomaps/) for instance), but I think what you'll want is either prefiltering the cloud and throw out intensities you don't in your octomap, or using the Octomap API and update the octomap manually with more control over how the update is performed.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0